# glibc issue in arch linux destroyed my system

Tags: arch-linux, glibc

I followed the article here

> http://www.archlinux.org/news/the-lib-directory-becomes-a-symlink/

Didn't work for me.
Then I followed an advice in the sticky thread in archlinux forum

> https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1136253#p1136253

and did following.

```
pacman -Rdd glibc
```

This has rendered my system useless. All of the commands are not found including pacman.
I don't want to reinstall arch. Is there any way to recover  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to boot your Sytem with the Arch Linux Live CD if you can't boot normally or can't do anything. I suggest you can boot but not do anything so boot from the Live CD.

You will have to `mount` your root mountpoint to mnt with

```
mount /dev/sdXXX /mnt
```

After that you `wget` the files you need from

```
https://www.archlinux.de/?page=Packages
```

Then you restore the packages by manually unpacking them by

```
sudo tar -xvpf !PKGNAME! -C /mnt --exclude .PKGINFO --exclude .INSTALL
```

(`!PKGNAME!` is the file name)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a try and let you know.